# Visual Studio 2008 and HP Quality Center 10 : are there any plugins?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, hp-quality-center

Do you know any plugin to use  HP Quality Center 10 from VS2008?

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tasktop](http://tasktop.com/) have some thing in beta, check out [this](http://www.sdtimes.com/TASKTOP_ANNOUNCES_BETA_OF_MICROSOFT_VISUAL_STUDIO_PLUGIN/By_SD_TIMES_NEWSWIRE/35021) article